# How to change button background in WPF xaml?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, button, background

Hello guys I'm new to WPF and XAML.
I'm stuck on changing the button background, image, colour or whatever, it just keeps being white.
It just shows the background when I double click on it in the visual editor so I can type some text on it, then it becomes white again.

Any clue about what I'm doing wrong?

```
<Button Margin="5,-7,5,-1" Width="59" Content="{Binding PlayContent}" x:Name="PlayPause"     HorizontalAlignment="Center" cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">
        <Button.Background>
              <ImageBrush ImageSource="resources/main_play_normal.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

thanks

Comment: check if main_play_normal.png has build action set as resource

Comment: yes it does. The point is that I can't even change the basic colour.

Comment: so you are saying '<Button Background="Blue"/>' does not set the background blue for u?

Comment: No, I only see that background while editting button's text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use style and template to modify your button behavior.

Here is a Metro Style for WPF Button try to use it :

```
  <Style
        x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter
            Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MetroButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEEEE"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 5"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border
                                x:Name="Border"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />

                            <ContentPresenter
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="OpacityMask" Value="#AA888888"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2 1" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="DimGray"/>-->
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

## EDIT

Try to use this style:

```
          <Style x:Key="GreenButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF3F9542" Offset="0.85"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Name="border" 
                BorderThickness="0"
                Padding="4,2" 
                BorderBrush="LightGray" 
                CornerRadius="2" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid >
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="contentShadow" >
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="content"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF4788c8" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF429C46"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF282828" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF282828" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                                </Trigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Then you just apply that style like this :

```
<Button x:Name="m_Button" Height="35" Content="Submit" Style="{StaticResource GreenButton}" IsEnabled="True" Click="m_Button_Click"/>
```

Comment: It is still shows a white button, background only changes when I text edit the butten, then when I finish text edit it comes back to default background

Comment: @user3678081 ok could you plz make it as answer and close that question, thks.

Comment: why you don't make it till ow

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like this,

```
<Button Margin="5,-7,5,-1" Width="59" x:Name="PlayPause">
    <Image Source="resources/main_play_normal.png"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: it says the property 'Content' is set more than once

Comment: @user3678081 Try the modified answer

Answer (score 0):

*If want to set image as background use

```
<Button x:Name="bt_cam"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,-7,5,-1" Height="80"Width="59" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Click="Button_Click"  >
                    <Button.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.3" ShadowDepth="12" />
                    </Button.Effect>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image x:Name="cam" Source="resources/main_play_normal.png" />
                    </StackPanel>
 </Button>
```

- If want to set background color,then remove the stackpannel and add background color on
  button

Comment: it says the property 'Content' is set more than once